# jQuery templating Engine : Not able to render html output

Tags: jquery, ajax, templates

My Templates are:

> ```
> <script id="tmplRiskInformation" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
>     <div class="">
>         {{tmpl(collection) "#tmplLimitsDeductible" }} 
>     </div>
>
> </script>
> <script id="tmplLimitsDeductible" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
>     <div>
>         ${LimitsDeductible} 
>     </div>
>
> </script>
> ```

The output is html from database and not rendering to browser. The value is a html table as

```
LimitsDeductible = "<table><tr><td>TEST TEST</td></tr></table>"
```

I have used the below but not getting the result as text not html.

```
${html LimitsDeductible} 
{{html ${LimitsDeductible} }}
```

Please find the output getting as 
[image]
The answer will be appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<script id="tmplLimitsDeductible" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div>
    {{html LimitsDeductible}}
  </div> 
</script>
```

See here for an example: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl/blob/master/demos/step-by-step/0_tmpl-read-only/2_html-tag-source.html